# "Cannot resolve symbol"error in create of Activity

Tags: android

I am using the latest version of Android Studio(3.6.1).
Creating a new "activity" in the project results in "cannot resolve symbol" error for all creations. It's fine after 'invalidate cache / restart'. But it is hassle for me. Is it because of the weakness of the latest version? Or please let me know a good way to solve it.

**Main2Activity**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }
}
```

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Attach code....

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin Sorry for didn't attach code. Just edited.

Comment: What is error? Attach image of that

Comment: It works fine now. Because I just restarted my IDE. But it's frequently got an issue like i described at top. And i knew how to solve it but it's hassle for me. So i just wonder, is it just an error of newest version of Android Studio.

Comment: If another one it shows error, send it

Comment: I'm using this version and haven't this problem

Comment: Just edited. Clean Project, Sync with File System, Sync project with Gradle Files those doesn't work. It only solved by restart projects.

Comment: Always it is this way?

Comment: Only works well in after restart projects.

Comment: It's strange for me. I haven't this problem but you have. Your Android Studio is in its latest version?

Comment: Yes i clicked check for updates, shows me already has the latest version of Android Studio and plugins. It's very tiresome but anyway after restart projects work fine. I will report this to google. Thank you for spend many time in my issues

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin please don't encourage users to post images of errors.  Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages, make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273) - the same reasoning applies to error messages as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it seems like android studio's bug. You can report this to google.